# OAuth 2.0 in WearOS app. Issue with Redirect Uri

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, wear-os

I'm trying to authenticate the user using an MFA. To be 100% clear I'm trying to use the new Tesla OAuth endpoints ([Unofficial docs](https://tesla-api.timdorr.com/api-basics/authentication#step-1-obtain-the-login-page)).

So one of the things in this OAuth is that the `redirect_uri` has to be `https://auth.tesla.com/void/callback` and CANNOT change because it will return a 400 error.

Is there a way I can use that OAuth in my app? I can't make that the browser on the phone redirects back to my app (on the watch) after logging in.

So code:

```java
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...

    mOAuthClient = OAuthClient.create(getApplicationContext());

    ...
}

public void signIn(View view) {
    ...

    String url = String.format("%s?client_id=%s&code_challenge=%s&code_challenge_method=%s&redirect_uri=%s&response_type=%s&scope=%s&state=%s",
            URL, CLIENT_ID, codeChallenge, CODE_CHALLENGE_METHOD, "https%3A%2F%2Fauth.tesla.com%2Fvoid%2Fcallback", RESPONSE_TYPE, SCOPE, STATE);

    performRequest(url, new OAuth2RequestCallback(this));
}

private void performRequest(String url, @Nullable OAuthClient.Callback callback) {
    mOAuthClient.sendAuthorizationRequest(Uri.parse(url), callback);
}
```